# MongoDB query with fields from different collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have no idea about how to build a query which does this:

I have a collection of users, each user has a field userdata which contains an array of String.
Each string is the string of the ObjectID of other documents (news already seen) in another collection.

I need, knowing the username of this user, to perform a query which gets all the news but not those which have been already seen.

I think the `$nin` operator does what I need but I don't know how to mix it with data from another collection.

```js
Users
    user
        username: String
        userdata: Object
            news: Array of String

News
    news1
        _id: ObjectID
    news2
        _id: ObjectID
```

EXAMPLE:

```js
Users: [{
    username: 'mario',
    userdata: {
        news: ['10', '11']
    }
}]
News: [{
    _id: '10',
    content: 'hello world10'
},{
    _id: '11',
    content: 'hello world11'
},{
    _id: '12',
    content: 'hello world12'
}]
```

Passing to the query the `username` (as a String) `'mario'`, I need to query the collection News and get back only the one with `_id '12'`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run [$lookup with custom pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries). There's no `$nin` for aggregations but you can use `$not` along with `$in`. Then you can also try [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) with [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to promote filtered `News` to the root level:

```
db.Users.aggregate([
    { $match: { username: "mario" } },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "News",
            let: { user_news: "$userdata.news" },
            pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $not: { $in: [ "$_id", "$$user_news" ]  } } } }],
            as: "filteredNews"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$filteredNews" },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$filteredNews" }}
])
```

Comment: would you recommend this over doing 2 different query?

Comment: using $lookup should be faster, if you really need two queries then you can use `$nin` but I would try using one

Comment: I've tried with this one you suggested, unlickily it returns all the news anyway. May it be because I store the object IDs as String inside userdata? If so, how to make it work?

Comment: @Mattia types needs to be the same. Use $toString or $toObjectId on `$_id` to convert one way or another